# Best way of dynamically setting color of control at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

I currently load controls at run time, and want to set the color, but not a named color.
I was thinking I need to create a color object , set the color of this then assign it, any direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Color.FromName() method to set colors :

```
txt.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#00B300");
txt.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("red");
```